# Run 2 versions of Blender

Tags: osx, compatibility

Can I use 2 versions of Blender? I have v3.0 can I create in v3.0 will it work in older an version? I'm using Mac in case this ie relevant.

Comment: Yes, you can run two versions.  No, files saved in 3.0 won't be right when run in earlier versions.  Best way to learn this is to try; it takes about as much time as it takes me to write this comment.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your reply.

Comment: [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/248243/42221) will help you migrate to V3. [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/245496/42221) talks about running two versions at once.  You might want to [take the tour](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour).  Sometimes you can find answers to your questions faster if you [search](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/searching) for similar questions before asking one.